# PyInstaller add root certificate to executable

Tags: python, ssl, pyinstaller

I have created a Python application and am packaging it with PyInstaller. On my own computer, I have configured my own trust store CA bundle to include my company's proxy based on [Self-Signed Certificate Authorities pip / conda](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but I don't understand how to bring that into the PyInstaller executable so it works on other people's computers who have not configured their own trust store CA bundle.

The error I get is `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain`

I am using PyInstaller 5.7.0 (with --onefile option), certifi 2022.12.7, and Python 3.8. This is primarily a dash application (2.7.1). First, the user selects a ZIPcode and I use uszipcode (version 0.2.6) to get information on that ZIPcode. That is where the error first occurs.

The application runs correctly when disconnected from the VPN. When I generate the executable, I use the --add-data flag to include cacert.pem from the certifi Python package. I tried manually adding my company's cert to the cacert.pem but it will get overwritten if I update certifi.

Where should I add in my company's SSL certificate so users don't have to disconnect from the VPN to use the application?